# Dynamically load Android widget

Tags: android

I have a fragment in which currently a textview and a button are being displayed. Upon clicking the button, a map should load in the fragment which covers the screen. Is there any way of doing this in Android (i.e any widget classes etc.)?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Comment: but won't that load the activity with the map itself? in my case, the user clicks on the button, the location is fetched from a background service, and then displayed on a map in that activity. that is when the map loads.

Comment: There's also a MapFragment, that can be added to an Activity dynamically. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map?hl=es#add_a_map_to_an_android_application